# Application Icon

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I have 3 icons. When I compile application I use first Icon - main app icon.
And I have 2 other icons in resources.

When I show MessageBox.Show(...) the first app icon appear in task bar.
I want to have an ability to change the main icon at runtime at some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's straight forward, take a look at this [article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/createiconsforsystemtray.asp) it might help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the icon that appears inside the message box by using P/Invoke to call the Windows [`MessageBoxIndirect`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/MessageBoxIndirect.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

While it's already mentioned here about P/Invoke - there is a good article about changing icon http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/MessageBoxIndirectCS.aspx if you don't want to write own MessageBox.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Drawing .Icon ica= new Icon (Application.StartupPath + "\\" + "my_new_icon.ico");

 this.Icon = ica; //This is an Active Form
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can change the icon for a standard MessageBox. You might have to make your own MesageBox. Then it's just changing the icon for a standard winform. That has been documented extensively both on MSDN and a lot of pages that can be found with Google.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the standard MessageBox.Show() method can't show a custom icon (you can specify from a few different ones in the enumeration, but you can't put an arbitrary one there), but if you have a normal .NET form, just set the 'Icon' property to the image you'd like and it works.  When doing this at runtime, the normal suspend/resume layout calls before and after might be necessary, or they might not, I dunno, but it shouldn't be a huge chore to set a property on a form.